# Issues on adding wild card custom domain SSL certificates to Azure front door

Tags: ssl-certificate, cloudflare, azure-front-door

Issue:
Failed to create the custom domain 'wildcard'. Error: The certificate chain includes an invalid number of certificates. The number of certificates should be greater than 2.

we have tried below methods:

1. from cloudflare, we downloaded origin, root and private key in .pem format. Executed below command to convert to pfx.
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -certfile cabundle.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out certificateandkey.pfx

When we upload this pfx in azure frontdoor, below error is displaying.
**Failed to create the custom domain 'wildcard'. Error: The certificate chain includes an invalid number of certificates. The number of certificates should be greater than 2.**

Please help me on this.

Issue:
Failed to create the custom domain 'wildcard'. Error: The certificate chain includes an invalid number of certificates. The number of certificates should be greater than 2.

we have tried below methods:

1. from cloudflare, we downloaded origin, root and private key in .pem format. Executed below command to convert to pfx.
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -certfile cabundle.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out certificateandkey.pfx

When we upload this pfx in azure frontdoor, below error is displaying.
**Failed to create the custom domain 'wildcard'. Error: The certificate chain includes an invalid number of certificates. The number of certificates should be greater than 2.**

Comment: Hi @K Nagaraj   Check the certificate chain in the PFX file `openssl pkcs12 -in certificateandkey.pfx -nokeys -chain | grep -v '^\s*$' | wc -l`This will count the no of certificates in the chain. If the no of certificates is less than 2, then the PFX file is not valid.

Comment: If No of certificates is less than 2, then you can try to download the intermediate certificate from the certificate authority (CA) that issued the certificate and add it to the PFX file using this cmd: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -certfile cabundle.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out certificateandkey.pfx`Replace `cabundle.pem` with the path to the intermediate certificate.

Comment: If the intermediate certificate is not available, then you can try to download the root certificate from the CA and add it to the PFX file using the following command:   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -certfile root.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out certificateandkey.pfx`

Replace `root.pem` with the path to the root certificate.

Comment: Hi Imran
Thanks for the reply.
I executed below command to create pfx.
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -certfile root.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out certificateandkey.pfx Replace root.pem with the path to the root certificate

After that I validated pfx with below command
"openssl pkcs12 -in certificateandkey.pfx -nokeys -chain | grep -v '^\s*$' | wc -l"

I obtained output as 50
And Getting the same error when i upload to azure frontdoor.

Comment: FYI, root ca certificate downloaded from this url. https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca#4-required-for-some-add-cloudflare-origin-ca-root-certificates

Answer (score 0):

To use your certificate with Azure Front Door, check the [requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/domain#certificate-requirements) and completed certificate chain.

> The certificate must have a complete certificate chain with leaf and intermediate certificates. The root CA must be part of the [Microsoft Trusted CA List](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFT). If a certificate without complete chain is presented, the requests which involve that certificate are not guaranteed to work as expected refer this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-configure-https-custom-domain?tabs=powershell#using-your-own-certificate)

Ensure that Custom TLS certificates must be imported into Azure Key Vault before you can use it with Azure Front Door. refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate?tabs=azure-portal)

In your key vault -> under object select certificates -> Generate/Import -> import your certificate like below:

[image]

[image]

If you already have a certificate, you can upload it to your key vault. Otherwise, create a new certificate directly through Azure Key Vault from one of the partner certificate authorities (CAs) that Azure Key Vault integrate.